# Javascript parameter recieving not working

Tags: javascript, dom

```js
var num = getQueryVariable("param1");

function getQueryVariable(variable) {
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    if (pair[0] == variable) {
      return pair[1];
    }
  }
  alert('Query Variable ' + variable + ' not found');
}

function mynewFunction {
  var numnew = num + 1;
  window.location = "?image=" + numnew;
}

function myFunction() {
  var numnew = num - 1;
  window.location = "?image=" + numnew;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<button onclick="mynewFunction()" id="forward"><i class="fa fa-backward"></i>
</button>
<button onclick="mysecondnewFunction()"></button>
<button onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fa fa-forward"></i>
</button>
```

I want the above code to change the parameter "image" to 2 when the URL is `/gallerySingle.htm?image=1` when I press the forward button, but it does not change anything.

Comment: Didn’t you see the syntax error in your console? “`SyntaxError`: missing `(` before formal parameters”. Always check your console if your code isn’t working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I noticed was that `mynewFunction` is not defined correctly, you're missing `()`

```
function mynewFunction() {
  var numnew = num + 1;
  window.location = "?image=" + numnew;
}
```